# Замена данных в исходящем POST по условию

Tags: php, laravel

Есть `radio`-переключатель, имеет `name="group"`

положение_1 имеет `value="1"`
положение_2 имеет форму ввода даты `name="time"`

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при положении_1 в значение POST-массива по ключу `"time"` подставлялась текущая дата

```
if (Input::get('group') == '1') {
            Input::flashOnly('time', Carbon::now());
            // еще так пробовал
            //$request->time = Carbon::now();
}
```

а `dd(Input::all());` все равно показывает, что time не входит в POST (вовсе отсутствует)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `Input::flashOnly` делает совсем другое, он сохраняет данные в сессию и нужен, чтобы передавать текущий ввод между запросами. В вашем случае скорее всего подойдет метод `Input::merge()`, который добавляет новые данные к текущему вводу, например, так:

```
if (Input::get('group') == 1) {
    Input::merge(array('time' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, в `dd(Input::all())` теперь есть `time`, а в БД не сохраняет, хотя формат аналогичен, как и с `<input name="time">`. С инпута в POST приходит `yyyy-mm-dd`, сейвит `2018-12-11 00:00:00`, с `merge` тоже приходит `yyyy-mm-dd`, `replace` тоже пробовал

Comment: @Tarasovych, а как сохраняете в БД?

Comment: просто `ModelName::create($request->all())`, в `rules` никаких правил нету на счет этого поля

Comment: @Tarasovch, сложно так сказать в чем дело, приведите метод обработки запроса полностью.

Comment: http://ideone.com/5AOPNH @MaximZasorin

Comment: @Tarasovych, попробуйте `$request->merge()` вместо `Input::merge()`.

Comment: Действительно, спасибо! Исправьте ответ, пожалуйста, я отметил решением!